# AIR - Resizing Native Window Proportionately

Tags: actionscript-3, air, resize, window

my application launches with the stage size of 1000 x 500, 2:1 aspect ratio.  the native window has system chrome, which will always be a little taller by a few pixels.

how is it possible to only permit a native window to resize proportionately in order to always maintain the 2:1 aspect ratio of the stage?

the following code doesn't work as i expect:

```
package
{
//Imports
import flash.display.NativeWindow;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.NativeWindowBoundsEvent;

//Class
[SWF(width="1000", height="500", frameRate="60", backgroundColor="#000000")]
public class WindowTest extends Sprite
    {
    //Constants
    private static const ASPECT_RATIO:Number = 2.0; //2:1 Aspect Ratio

    //Constructor
    public function WindowTest()
        {
        init();
        }

    //Initialization
    private function init():void
        {
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.nativeWindow.addEventListener(NativeWindowBoundsEvent.RESIZE, windowResizeEventHandler);
        }

    //Window Resize Event Handler
    private function windowResizeEventHandler(evt:NativeWindowBoundsEvent):void
        {
        evt.currentTarget.width = stage.stageHeight * ASPECT_RATIO;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prevent the default event, and resize the window manually:
EDIT: it seems, that air is calculating the width in a weird way, so to prevent flickering in the beginning set the window size to 1050x500 in the SWF tag.

```
package{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.NativeWindowBoundsEvent;

//Class
[SWF(width="1000", height="500", frameRate="60", backgroundColor="#000000")]
public class airtest extends Sprite
{
    //Constants
    private static const ASPECT_RATIO:Number = 2.0; //2:1 Aspect Ratio

    //Constructor
    public function airtest()
    {
        init();
    }

    //Initialization


private function init():void
    {
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.nativeWindow.addEventListener(NativeWindowBoundsEvent.RESIZING, windowResizeEventHandler);
    }

    private function windowResizeEventHandler(evt:NativeWindowBoundsEvent):void
    {
        evt.preventDefault()
        if (evt.beforeBounds.width != evt.afterBounds.width){//user resizes width
            evt.currentTarget.width = evt.afterBounds.width
            evt.currentTarget.height = evt.afterBounds.width/ASPECT_RATIO;
        } else if (evt.beforeBounds.height != evt.afterBounds.height){
            evt.currentTarget.height = evt.afterBounds.height
            evt.currentTarget.width = evt.afterBounds.height*ASPECT_RATIO;
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: It works for me.. You need the beta flex 4.5 to compile Air actionscript projects. What is the error?

Comment: i'm using Flash Professional CS5 with the AIR 2.5 SDK.  why would i need the Flex SDK?  there is no error.  the window just simply does not resize at all.

Comment: hmh maybe because when i tried it i named the class airtest? You named it WindowTest

Comment: no, i changed the class name and constructor - otherwise it wouldn't compile.  i'm running your code in ADL.  evt.preventDefault(); causes the event to not happen and the subsequent code is not triggered, but removing evt.preventDefault(); results in the window not resizing proportionately.  it seems in both cases the subsequent code is ignored.  the same thing happens when i publish and run the program as an AIR application.

Comment: I compiled it in Flex 4.5 Beta and everything was fine. I only changed the windowResizeEventHandler function and modified to event from NativeWindowBoundsEvent.RESIZE to NativeWindowBoundsEvent.RESIZING.

The code should do the following:
NativeWindowBoundsEvent.RESIZING event occurs if an user interaction is detected, but before actual parameters of the window change. I cancel this event, because i want to resize the window manually. evt.beforeBounds contains the original window size, and evt.afterBounds contains the window size, after user interaction.

Comment: If the width changed (evt.beforeBounds.width != evt.afterBounds.width) then i set the width of the window manually to the user desired size, and set the height to the half of its new value. I do similar stuff, when the height changes. I can think of one more problem: maybe evt.currentTarget is not the application? (altough i dont know why it would differ at you..)

Comment: are you using any MXML by any chance?  or is it straight up AS3?  i find it difficult to believe that you can get this to work using the Flex+AIR SDKs while i can't using FlashCS5+AIR SDKs.

Comment: yes. since posting this question i've moved from Mac to a Windows environment and ditched Flash Professional completely in favor of FlashDevelop / Flash Builder using AIR 3.x.  Sydd's solution works great.

Comment: On Win 7, resizing from bottom_right, gives flickering. Also resizing from top_left is not correct. There must be a better way for this, and to make it work on Mac...

Comment: It works on window, but on macOS 10.10 event.preventDeafault causes some window lock: for a few frames nothing happends when I call set width or set height. It works only with 5-frame delayed call.

Comment: @Selirion I think the best way would be if AIR has additional property like in NativeWindowBoundsEvent.from_corner_or_side